# GitHub — как быть с недогружаемыми файлами?

Tags: android-studio, github

Пользуюсь `GitHub` на Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA. Заметил, что имена файлов в проводнике IDE имеют разные цвета — белый, красный, синий, зелёный.

Догадываюсь, что синий файл — изменённый, зелёный — созданный после последнего обновления, белый — не тронутый с последнего обновления, красный — созданный перед последним обновлением и по каким-то причинам не обновлённый. Поправьте, если я не прав.

Что точно означает расцветка файлов, не нашёл. Но ок.

Интересуют красные файлы. Сегодня подгрузил клон проекта на другой компьютер и убедился, что файлы, помеченные красным на компьютере, с которого происходят коммиты / пуши, не добавились на новый компьютер. А это уже не ок.

Подскажите, как быть в такой ситуации? Как закоммитить красные файлы? И что с ними не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Статус файлов в VCS в IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/file-status-highlights.html) описан в справке. Красный — конфликт после мерджа ("During the last update, file was merged with conflicts"). Вероятно, стоит разрешить конфликт.